# jQuery Validation Plugin - simple implementation

Tags: jquery, plugins, jquery-plugins, jquery-validate

I have this markup here and I wish to add a simple check to see if the user has
selected a size.  I am using the jQuery validation plugin I am not sure the best way 
to go about this. I can't change the markup because it's part of a custom cms.

```
        <form class="product-details">  
        <select class="w80 valid" id="mysize" required="required" title="Please select size!" name="mysize">
           <option value="11071">Select Size</option>
           <option value="11079">S</option>
           <option value="11080">M</option>
           <option value="11081">L</option>
           <option value="11082">XL</option>
           <option value="11089">XXL</option>
        </select>
        ...
        <button type="submit">Add</button>
        </form>
```

I know the logic would be something like this in vanilla jQuery:

```
        ( function($) {

           $(function (){  
               $('.product-details').submit(function(){
                 var mySize = $('#mysize');
                 var firstOption = mySize.find('option').first().val();
                 var userOption = mySize.find(':selected').val();
                 if( firstOption === userOption ) {
                    // fail
                    return false;
                    // trigger some error.
                 }
               });
           }); 

        } ) ( jQuery );
```

So how to use jQuery validate to do something similar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
$(function(){
    jQuery.validator.addMethod( 'notequals', function(value, element, param){
        return value != param;
    } , 'Please select a valid value')

    $('.product-details').validate({
        rules: {
            mysize: {
                notequals: $('#mysize').find('option').first().val()
            }
        }
    });
});
```

Demo: [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/KkDzXyNiWyLQOy6czgTY?p=preview)

Comment: Oh adding a new validation method AddMethod was the key. Thanks Arun!